# How to properly relate users to data in Redis and trigger updates according to a date field

Tags: database, database-design, redis, aws-lambda, node-redis

Hi Everyone I need some insight on an architecture question.

I want to use Redis to store a bunch of data that is constantly getting accessed and only gets updated 2-3 times per day. It gets manually updated by an aws lambda function. The thing is though there is an `EndDate` column in the Redis table and afterwards I want to update all the users that depend on that data whose end date is coming up. Do I store the list of users within the Redis table like the example below? Or should I figure out a separate approach?

```
Id  Column1     Column2     User_Id_List    End_Date
1   100         100         [1,2,3,4]       06-21-2020
2   100         100         [3,5,1,7]       06-22-2020
3   100         100         [9,2,1,4]       06-23-2020
4   100         100         [8,5,6,3]       06-24-2020
5   100         100         [4,8,2,9]       06-25-2020
6   100         100         [9,5,8,1]       06-26-2020
```

Comment: Hello Manny, welcome. How does it accessed ? What do you mean by "coming up"? do you need id, column1 and column2 for this architecture ?

Comment: Hi Ersoy! The cache would get accessed by the ID and it would be my "key" for Redis. I meant "coming up" by passing the date of "EndDate" so for the first row, at 6-22-2020 users from the user_id_list should be updated in their tables.. Column1 and Column2 are needed in my architecture yes. I just simplified the naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

What i may suggest is keeping the whole data in a single data type, `hash` but different keys for different queries. Each row including `column1`, `column2` and `useridlist` will be held in hashes with the `id` as an identifier. Another hash will be responsible for enddates with the combination of `id`.
I didn't put `end date` into the first hash group since it is used only to determine which userIds should be returned but if you need it you may put them as field too.

I initialized each row with `id:<number>` with `HSET`. Used another hash named `enddates` key to put enddates with the corresponding `id`s.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET id:1 column1 100 column2 100 users "[1,2,3,4]"
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET id:2 column1 100 column2 100 users "[3,5,1,7]"
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET id:3 column1 100 column2 100 users "[9,2,1,4]"
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET enddates 06-21-2020 1 06-22-2020 2 06-23-2020 3
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL enddates
1) "06-21-2020"
2) "1"
3) "06-22-2020"
4) "2"
5) "06-23-2020"
6) "3"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

When you query with `HGET` you may get the id (1 in the following lines) of the rows. If `HGET` doesn't return anything(second command) then you may discard it.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HGET enddates 06-21-2020
"1"
127.0.0.1:6379> HGET enddates 06-21-2022
(nil)
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Since you get `1`, you may get the users with the last command.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HGET id:1 users
"[1,2,3,4]"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Then in your application layer you may parse it to pass into the update query.